# Separability of $l_p(I,K)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Good day,

I have the following question

"Prove that for $1 \leq p < \infty$, $l_p(I,K)$ is separable if and only if $I$ is countable, and $l_{\infty}(I,K)$ is separable if and only if $I$ is finite."

From the lecture I know:

- A topological space is called separable iff it contains a countable, dense subset.
- $l_\infty(I,K)=\{f:I \to K: ~ ||f||_\infty = \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)| < \infty\}$, $l_p(I,K)=\{f:I \to K: ~ ||f||_p < \infty\}$ where $K$ is a field
- $||~ ||_p$ is a norm on $l_p(I,K)$ for $p \in [1,\infty]$
- $l_p(I,K)$ is Banach space for $p \in [1,\infty]$
- Lemma: A normed space $(X,||~||)$ is separable iff there is a countable set S such that $X=\overline{span(S)}$.
- $span(S):=\{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i : ~ n \in \mathbb{N}, x_i \in S,
     a_i \in \mathbb{R} \}$

I think have to use the Lemma to prove the first equivalence. But I have no approach how to prove this. Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot,
Marvin

Comment: Can $K$ be any field or is it short for reals or complex numbers?

Comment: $K$ must be a normed field, otherwise the definition of $l_p(I,K)$ makes no sense, and $K$ must be separable, otherwise the only separable $l_p(I,K)$ are $l_p(\varnothing,K) = \{0\}$. Probably, only $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are considered.

Comment: For "span" you should use coefficients from your field, so can it be something other than $\mathbb R$ or not?

Comment: yes, you are right, we only considered $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ for $K$. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finite $p$, suppose let $D$ be a countable dense set (containing $0$) of $K$ (which, as Daniel Fischer remarked in his comment) must exist, as $l_p(\{p\})$ for a singleton set $I$ is isomorphic to $K$.

Then all sequences from $D$ that eventually $0$ can be shown to be dense in $l_p(I,K)$

If $I$ is not countable, you can easily find $|I|$ many vectors in $l_p(I,K)$ that are $1$ apart in distance. This kills separability (why?).

For $l_\infty(I,K)$ we can always find $2^{|I|}$ many vectors that are 1 apart, and this is uncountable for $I$ non-finite.

The finite case should be easy to do for $l_\infty(I,K)$, I shoudl think. The obvious candidate (use $D$ again!) works.

Answer (score 0):

hint

To show $l_p(I,K)$ is separable.  First you need to find a good candidate for a countable set $S$ with closed span $l_p(I,K)$.